# Show content of custom page for any url in folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right now I want following feature.

```
domain.com/blablarandomnames/.... - must show domain.com/index.php
```

and

```
domain.com/claim/anyrandomnames/... - must show domain.com/claim/url.php
```

I tried below code , But only  `domain.com/blablarandomnames/` is working  , not the another one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^claim(\/?)$ claim/url.php [QSA,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*)(\/?)$ / [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Does your `/claim/` folder also have a .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^claim.*$ claim/url.php [QSA,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [NC,L]
```

Comment: yea ,, now working...btw when claim folder is accessed its showing url.php ..i wanna show index.php with just claim foder is accessed